# access QBE to count record number

Tags: count, ms-access-2007

I am a new user in Access. I am trying to use count function to calculate the total records number in my table. How can I use QBE (not sql) to achieve it please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag a field - preferably a unique ID field - into the QBE gid, and click the "Totals" button on the Ribbon Bar.

You'll now see a new row in the QBE called "Total:". This is a combo box- select Count from it, and run the query.

Comment: Thanks, fix it. Just have some stupid error by selecting more than one column each time before.